# How to disable Microsoft Authenticator notification

Tags: windows, notifications

I keep on getting ads in the Windows 10 Notification Center to sign up for Microsoft Authenticator. I keep on suppressing the ads but they keep on coming back. Is there a way to permanently disable these ads?

Comment: I suspect if you disable `Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows` within `Notifications & actions`.  If that works for you I will submit an answer, I have it enabled, but I never get that suggestion so I am not entirely sure that will prevent the notification.  I also don't know if you are actually getting a notification or not.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me, though it does turn off a little more than just that notification.

After getting the notification, don't click on the cross or remove it.

1. Open the notification drawer
2. You should see the suggestion under a title of "Suggestions"
3. Right click on the title "Suggestions" and select "Turn off notifications for Suggestions"

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Authenticator prompt is maybe coming up because you turned on
[Two-step verification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12408/microsoft-account-about-two-step-verification).

Try this from the article
[Turning two-step verification on or off for your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028586/microsoft-account-turning-two-step-verification-on-or-off) :

> - Go to [Security settings](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=529561) and sign in
>     with your Microsoft account.
> - Under the **Two-step verification** section choose ... **Turn off two-step verification** to turn it off.
> - Follow the instructions.

Comment: I'm logged in using a Local Account (not a linked to a Microsoft Account) so I don't think this applies in my case. Further, I checked my Microsoft Account and it seems to have two-step verification disabled.

Comment: Can you add to your post a screenshot of this message?

Comment: I will, the next time it comes up.

Comment: Like @Gili I'm also using a Local Account with 2-step off and get the Authenticator notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to PC Settings -> System -> Notifications & actions. "Suggested" switch can found at the bottom. Here you'll find all applications that have the ability to pop-up notifications and the switches to turn the authorization on or off.

Answer (score -1):

I use the registry to disable notifications, the specific steps are as follows:

1. Press the **WINDOWS+R** key on the desktop, and then open the Run menu window and enter "**regedit**" to open Registry Editor.

[image]

2. After entering Windows Registry Editor, we navigate to the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows** project, double-click on the item on the left and open them.

[image]

3. After we find the last Windows subkey, we right-click the subkey and select the **New->key** menu.

[image]

4. In the pop-up menu, name the item "**Explorer**", then right-click on the new Explorer item, select **New-Dword (32-bit)**, and then type "**DisableNotificationCenter**" in the Open page.

[image]

[image]

5. Double-click to establish the **DisableNotificationCenter** subkey item, open it and set the value data to "**1**", and then click the OK button.

[image]

6. Save the change settings for the registry, and then right-click in the taskbar on the desktop and select Open **Task Manager**. Locate the **Windows Explorer** in Task Manager, and then **Restart** the Explorer program.

[image]

**Tip**: If you want to restore the list of WIN10 notification bar programs, you only need to delete the Explorer items in the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows** directory in the registry. Then restart the Windows Explorer.

Comment: I don't want to disable all notifications, just this specific one.

Comment: Anyway this trick doesn't disable the Authenticator notification, it just disables the notification center icon on the system tray, so this is a useless solution.